# How to convert string column to ArrayType in pyspark

Tags: cassandra, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have requirement where, I need to mask the data stored in Cassandra tables using pyspark. I have a frozen data set in Cassandra which I get it as Array in pyspark. I converted it to String for masking it. Now, I want to convert it back to array type.

I am using spark 2.3.2 to mask data from Cassandra table. I copied data to a data frame and converted it to string to perform masking. I tried to convert it back to array However, I am not able to maintain the original structure.

```
table_df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")
networkinfos_df= sqlContext.sql('Select  networkinfos , pid, eid, s sid From tmp  ')


dfn1 = networkinfos_df.withColumn('networkinfos_ntdf',regexp_replace(networkinfos_df.networkinfos.cast(StringType()),r'\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b', faker.ipv4_private(network=False, address_class=None))).drop('networkinfos') \
.withColumn('networkinfos_ntdf',regexp_replace('networkinfos_ntdf',r'([a-fA-F0-9]{2}[:|\-]?){6}', faker.mac_address())) \
.withColumn('networkinfos_ntdf',regexp_replace('networkinfos_ntdf',r'(([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,2}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,3}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,5}|[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,6})|:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)|fe80:(:[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9]))', faker.ipv6(network=False))) \
.drop('networkinfos') 

dfn2 = dfn1.withColumn("networkinfos_ntdf", array(dfn1["networkinfos_ntdf"]))

dfn2.show(30,False)
```

The original structure it as follows:

```
enter code here
|-- networkinfos: array (nullable = true)

 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)

 |    |    |-- vendor: string (nullable = true)

 |    |    |-- product: string (nullable = true)

 |    |    |-- dhcp_enabled: boolean (nullable = true)

 |    |    |-- dhcp_server: string (nullable = true)

 |    |    |-- dns_servers: array (nullable = true)

 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

 |    |    |-- ipv4: string (nullable = true)

 |    |    |-- ipv6: string (nullable = true)

 |    |    |-- subnet_mask_obsolete: string (nullable = true)

 |    |    |-- default_ip_gateway: string (nullable = true)

 |    |    |-- mac_address: string (nullable = true)

 |    |    |-- logical_name: string (nullable = true)

 |    |    |-- dhcp_lease_obtained: timestamp (nullable = true)

 |    |    |-- dhcp_lease_expires: timestamp (nullable = true)

 |    |    |-- ip_enabled: boolean (nullable = true)

 |    |    |-- ipv4_list: array (nullable = true)

 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

 |    |    |-- ipv6_list: array (nullable = true)

 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

 |    |    |-- subnet_masks_obsolete: array (nullable = true)

 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

 |    |    |-- default_ip_gateways: array (nullable = true)

 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- wins_primary_server: string (nullable = true)


 |    |    |-- wins_secondary_server: string (nullable = true)

 |    |    |-- subnet_mask: string (nullable = true)

 |    |    |-- subnet_masks: array (nullable = true)

 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

 |    |    |-- interface_index: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- speed: long (nullable = true)

 |    |    |-- dhcp_servers: array (nullable = true)

 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

**What I am getting is:**

```
root
 |-- pid: string (nullable = true)

 |-- eid: string (nullable = true)

 |-- sid: string (nullable = true)

 |-- networkinfos_ntdf: array (nullable = false)

 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

How can I get it converted to original structure?

Comment: you can use spark sql function split to split it back
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#split-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 1):

You can try using pyspark.sql.functions.**to_json()** and pyspark.sql.functions.**from_json()** to handle your task if your **regexp_replace** operations do not break the JSON data:

First find the schema for the field `networkinfos`:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, from_json, to_json

# get the schema of the array field `networkinfos` in JSON
schema_data = df.select('networkinfos').schema.jsonValue()['fields'][0]['type']

# convert it into pyspark.sql.types.ArrayType:
field_schema = ArrayType.fromJson(schema_data)
```

After you have the field_schema, you can use from_json to set it back to its original schema from the modified JSON strings:

```
dfn1 = networkinfos_df \
        .withColumn('networkinfos', to_json('networkinfos')) \
        .withColumn('networkinfos', regexp_replace('networkinfos',...)) \
        .....\
        .withColumn('networkinfos', from_json('networkinfos', field_schema))
```